# "A book of mine" vs "A book of my own"

Tags: pronouns

- I found this question while doing an exercise:

---Find the mistake:

```
     -"This is abook of mine."
```

I think the answer is:

```
    -"This is a book of mine.", Isn't it?
```

And is it right to say:

```
     -"This is a book of my own."
```

Does this make difference?

Comment: This just looks like a typo. You're right though, it should be **a book**. In this instance you could use **my own** but it is not interchangeable in all circumstances. Consider: *This is **my own** way of writing.* I could use **my** but never **mine**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. It's a simple matter of typo. "A book of mine" is valid, it means "my book". You might probably have heard of this style of speaking like "a friend of mine", and no, [it doesn't mean "a friend of a friend"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77793/why-a-friend-of-mine-is-not-my-friends-friend). "A book of my own" is grammatically correct

Answer (score 0):

: "This is a book of my own." Doesn't sound very natural, but anyway it means that it belongs only to you,to nobody else.It would be more natural to say; "I have a book of my own." As for the first sentence, you're right. "This is a book of mine."
In the first sentence you're stressing the fact that you have something that belongs only to you, whereas in he second you're  just stating that the book is yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is a book of mine.

This is a book of my own. (Pls refer to Oxford D. for "of my own")

Semantically, both the sentences have the same meaning, with the only difference the former means that this is a book that belongs to me whereas the latter puts emphasis that this is a book that belongs to me.  Another example: He is a child of mine/He is a child of my own.

It's more usual to say that "This book is mine/This is my own book".